# Using a playlist instead of ids

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I want to use "`OLAK5uy_l6d6ubzR8UphJyEvUM0Qr1Z8uD0H7MAqA`" instead of "`6bDmN0z74M8`"

How would I do that,

```
listType: "playlist",
list: "OLAK5uy_nu2pWHv90t3dI6vP92Bzq4JMKbRVp-FvI",

OLAK5uy_nBgqeHieyRYocBrDqSLprkkE5U8Y-m3MU
OLAK5uy_krkRFyApOZAREaeL6AsddFHv61BKM6nQc
OLAK5uy_nXJ9YSCDX2jJEFOpyn0kQXIyY9KsBSt-k
OLAK5uy_l6d6ubzR8UphJyEvUM0Qr1Z8uD0H7MAqA
```

In this code? https://jsfiddle.net/18d5jhme/

**My attempt:** https://jsfiddle.net/18d5jhme/1/

2nd attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/18d5jhme/2/

```
const tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

let players = [];
let videoIds = ['6bDmN0z74M8', '_RLTUguVO8g', 's0ZZHNRHA2g', 'wUiDnrA5Kss', '1Q1aDAnBsU8'];

function onPlayerReady(event) {
  player = event.target;
  player.setVolume(100);
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
    for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
      if (players[i] !== event.target) players[i].pauseVideo();
    }
  }
}

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  for (let i = 0; i < videoIds.length; i++) {
    players[i] = new YT.Player('ytplayer' + i, {
      height: '361',
      host: 'https://www.youtube-nocookie.com',
      width: '642',
      videoId: videoIds[i],
      playerVars: {
        autoplay: 0,
        cc_load_policy: 0,
        controls: 1,
        disablekb: 1,
        fs: 0,
        iv_load_policy: 3,
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific and clear about what you're trying to do and what's the problem, please?

Comment: I want to use "OLAK5uy_l6d6ubzR8UphJyEvUM0Qr1Z8uD0H7MAqA" instead of "6bDmN0z74M8"

Comment: You would need to change your call to YT.Player for a playlist instead of a single video.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123143/how-to-play-a-playlist-using-youtube-javascript-api

Comment: There are 5 playlist links, How do I do that?

Comment: My attempt: https://jsfiddle.net/18d5jhme/1/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Play a Playlist using YouTube JavaScript API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5123143/how-to-play-a-playlist-using-youtube-javascript-api)

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/p10c4kga/

```
// Full code for embedding and controlling multiple YouTube playlists

// Create the script tag to load the YouTube IFrame Player API
const tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api';
const firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// Array of playlist IDs
const playlistIds = [
  "OLAK5uy_nBgqeHieyRYocBrDqSLprkkE5U8Y-m3MU",
  "OLAK5uy_nXJ9YSCDX2jJEFOpyn0kQXIyY9KsBSt-k",
  "OLAK5uy_nBgqeHieyRYocBrDqSLprkkE5U8Y-m3MU",
  "OLAK5uy_nXJ9YSCDX2jJEFOpyn0kQXIyY9KsBSt-k",
  "OLAK5uy_l6d6ubzR8UphJyEvUM0Qr1Z8uD0H7MAqA"
];

// Array to store the player instances
let players = [];

// Function to set the volume of the player to 100 when it's ready
function onPlayerReady(event) {
  player = event.target;
  player.setVolume(100);
}

// Function to pause other players when one player starts playing
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data === YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
    for (let i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
      if (players[i] !== event.target) players[i].pauseVideo();
    }
  }
}

// Function to create a player for each playlist
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  for (let i = 0; i < playlistIds.length; i++) {
    players[i] = new YT.Player('ytplayer' + i, {
      height: '361',
      host: 'https://www.youtube-nocookie.com',
      width: '642',
      playerVars: {
        autoplay: 0,
        listType: 'playlist',
        list: playlistIds[i],
        cc_load_policy: 0,
        controls: 1,
        disablekb: 1,
        fs: 0,
        iv_load_policy: 3,
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
}
```